# Tomcat 8.5.51/Tomcat 9.0.31 - HTTP/1.1 port is not updated in server.xml when changing it via the UI installation

Tags: port, tomcat8, tomcat9

I installed Tomcat 8.5.51/Tomcat 9.0.31 and during the installation, I changed the HTTP/1.1 port to 80.

[image]

but after the installation, I saw in server.xml that the port wasn't changed.

[image]

If I install Tomcat 8.5.27/Tomcat 9.0.27 it works correctly.
do you have any idea what went wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64206) in 8.5.51 and 9.0.31.

It is fixed in 8.5.52 and 9.0.32 that should be released early next week. Meanwhile just edit server.xml after install.

Comment: Thank you! can you add a reference to this known bug?